# PHP_Tools / flex_exec - cannot run the tools - Invalid choice: 'builds'

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-tools to run some commands on a running App Engine docker container.

1. I installed the php_tools package
2. I run the following command: `./vendor/bin/flex_exec run -- php -v`

I get the following errors:

```
Using service: default
Using version: ...
Using image: eu.gcr.io/...
Using cloudSqlInstances: ...
Using workdir: /private/var/folders/jd/mklbdfms2hsgm9mm7glf438m0000gn/T/flex-exect5qUQs_workdir
Running command: php -v
ERROR: (gcloud.container) Invalid choice: 'builds'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud builds submit
  gcloud config get-value
  gcloud config list
  gcloud config set
  gcloud config unset

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

In ContainerExec.php line 113:
                             
  Failed to run the command  
                             

run [-s|--service SERVICE] [-t|--target-version TARGET-VERSION] [-i|--image IMAGE] [--cloud-sql-instances CLOUD-SQL-INSTANCES] [-p|--preserve-workdir] [-d|--workdir] [--] <commands>...
```

Is possible the PHP_Tools need to be fixed to use the latest gcloud commands?

Thanks

Comment: Can You mention the complete command that you are using in the line 113?

Comment: Sure, it's here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-tools/blob/35568f84c2bab20d5ac9c5b4ba4b86654c834fcc/src/Utils/ContainerExec.php#L113

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So the error here is because the version of this library installed via composer has a bug in it. If you use the version from Github it might work. The bug is, specifically, that it is running "`gcloud container builds submit` '' instead of "`gcloud builds submit`".

You should be able to set up your local environment so you can run the type of command this script is supposed to help with. This will also be much quicker than doing so via Cloud Build, which is what this script tries to do.

For more information you can refer to Public [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart)  where deployment of  PHP apps  in the App Engine Flexible environment is explained.